# Create a lot of 200 different Email Accounts in a short span of time?

Tags: email, scripting, user-accounts, spam-prevention

I am trying to send bulk email from a few accounts email accounts, and for some reason, I think the emails get blocked  and they do not reach the recipient. I think it is because of spam / filtering rules. Is it possible for me to create say 100 different email accounts in a very short amount of  time and send 1 email from each of the accounts ?

Is there any service/ idea / script to create a lot of email accounts in a very short amount of time ?

Comment: What genuine reason could you possibly have for doing this?

Comment: It's just for marketing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set it up easily using Yahoo Mail Plus. They had the feature of Disposable Email Accounts. You can create 500 of them !

Answer (score 1):

Creating 100+ accounts on your own server would be pointless. It's usually the originating server and isp and/or the email's content that causes it to be flagged as spam. Creating 100+ accounts elsewhere MAY work, but then each of those other servers may also be considered as a spam source and any mails you send from that particular account will go missing as well.

You can check your mail server's logs to see if the mails get dumped by the receiving mail server. Some of them will do the filtering right at the initial connection/send attempt. However, some will pretent to accept the mail (and you see a `200 OK` acceptance message), but then toss the mail in the trash automatically. In this case, you'd nave no idea what happened, as everything would appear to have worked fine.